# nginx try files subdirectory dont work

Tags: nginx

I have configuration file where i am using root dir beyond public_html because i want to separate static files and php.

```
      root /home/user/domain;

       location / {        
       try_files  /static/$uri /static/$uri/ /php/index.php?$args;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {          
       fastcgi_pass hiphop;
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
       try_files  /static/$uri /static/$uri/ /php/index.php?$args;
      }
```

where i am mistaking?

Comment: Are you seeing that `/static/$uri` is loading when you request a location where you want something else to load?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is flawed. For example, the `/static/$uri/` causes an external redirect, which means that `/static/` URIs will be presented to your server, that your config will attempt to resolve as `/static/static/`. The `try_files` in the PHP location is attempting to execute `/static/` files as PHP scripts.

Have you considered using two `root` directives? Maybe:

```
root /home/user/domain/static;

location / {        
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    root /home/user/domain/php;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    fastcgi_pass hiphop;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
}
```